# open ball definition and bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces

> Let $A: V \rightarrow W$ be a linear map between normed space.
>   Then the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> $\left ( a \right ):A$ is continuous at$ \vec{0}$
>
> $\left ( b \right ) A$ is continuous
>
> $\left ( c \right )A$ is bounded

Proof:

$\left ( a \right )IFF\left ( c \right ):$
Assuming A is continuous at $\vec{0}$,then using the open ball definition of continuity, for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that 
$v \in B_{\delta}\left ( \vec{0} \right )\Rightarrow Av \in B_{\epsilon}\left ( \vec{0} \right )$.

I don't understand how using the open ball definition for continuity leads to the above implication.

[image]
Can someone shed some light?

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what you mean by "open ball definition for continuity" explicitly, so that we can tell you how it is used here.

Comment: Let me add it to the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Walk the proof $(b)\rightarrow(a)\rightarrow(c)\rightarrow(b)$

$(b)\rightarrow(a)$ is clear

$(a)\rightarrow(c)$:From continuity follows, that  $\delta > 0$ exists with $A B_V(0,\delta) \subseteq B_W (0,1)$, therefore $||Ax||_W \leq 1$ for every $x \in B_V(0,\delta)$. Then by homogenity $||A||_W \leq \frac{1}{\delta} ||x||_V$ for every $x \in V$.

$(c)\rightarrow(b)$: Let $x \in X$ and you know $||Ax-Ay||_W\leq M||x-y||_V$ ; so from $||x-y||_V\leq \frac{\epsilon}{M}$ follows 
$||Ax-Ay||_W\leq \epsilon$ and A is uniformly continuous and therefore continous.

q.e.d.

Comment: Answer for details^^

Comment: If A is bounded, what can I say? I ask because the definition for a linear map A is bounded IF ".....". It goes one way.

Comment: If A is bounded you can say$ ||Ax||_W\leq M||x||_V$ for any $x \in X$ for constant $M\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$

Comment: But doesn't the definition cuts only the "if" direction?

Comment: I don't understand your question: that is the definition of bounded linear maps

Comment: I don't understand it too. A linear map A:V->W between Normed spaces is called BOUNDED IF there exists a constant K>=0 such that "....".
Where is the ONLY IF condition?
Based on this definition which came from my notes, there is obviously nothing i can say if A is bounded.

Comment: Ah now I understand^^ To ne bounded is just a name another example: bounded functions  here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function; you can't show the direction if M exists ..then it is bounded because that is your definition; you can only show it if you had another equivalence, because every equivalence can be uses as a definition - but in this case, it's just a name - better now?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Given continuity at $\vec{0}$, to prove continuity at any other point $\vec{v}$, consider a sequence $\{\vec{v_{n}}\}_{n\geq 1}$ such that $\vec{v_{n}}\rightarrow \vec{v}$. What can you say about the sequence $\{\vec{v}-\vec{v_{n}}\}_{n\geq 1}$?

Comment: It is a sequences of distance function.

Comment: Assuming that there is a metric established to define the notion of convergence, observe that the sequence I asked you about converges to $\vec{0}$. Now, can you invoke the continuity result at $\vec{0}$ to complete the problem?

Comment: Observe that $V$ and $W$ are normed spaces